# Kafka Streams reduceByKey vs. leftJoin

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

At first glance it seems to me that with a `KStream#reduceByKey` one can achieve the same functionality as with a `KStream to KTable leftJoin`. I.e combining records with the same key. What i the difference between the two, also in terms of performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Short answer:* (What is the difference between the two?)

`reduceByKey` is applied to a **single input stream** while `leftJoin` combines **two streams/tables**.

*Long answer:*

If I understand your question correctly, it seems that your incoming `KTable` changelog stream would be empty, and you want to compute a new join result (ie, update result `KTable`) for each incoming `KStream` record? The result `KTable` of a join is not available as materialized view, but only the changelog topic will be sent downstream. Thus, your input `KTable` would always be empty and your input `KStream` record, would always join with "nothing" (because of left join), which would not be really be update the result `KTable`. You could also do a `KStream#map()` -- there is no state you can exploit if your input `KTable` does not provide a state.

In contrast, if you use `reduceByKey`, the result `KTable` is available as materialized view, and thus for each `KStream` input record, the previous result value is available to get updated.

Thus, both operations are fundamentally different. If you have a single input `KStream` using a join (that required two inputs) would be quite odd, as there is no `KTable`...

Answer (score 1):

KStream represents a record stream in which each record is self contained. For example, if we are to summarize word occurrences, it would hold the count during a certain frame (e.g. time window or paragraph). 
KTable represents a sort of a state and, each record coming in, would normally hold the total occurrences count.
Therefore, the use case to which each method is used is quite different. While KStream#reduceByKey would reduce all records in the same key and summarize the counts for each key, KTable#leftJoin would normally be used in cases when the total count needs to be adjusted according to another information coming in, or combining more data to the record.
The example given in Kafka Stream's documentation is for log compaction. While with KStream, no record could be discarded, in KTable, records that are no longer relevant would be removed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if I want to update an existing record in the `KTable` (local store) by the incoming one from `KStream`, both methods gathers the records by a given key. I'm still unsure about the difference, as for both implementation `reduceByKey: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Reducer` and `leftJoin: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueJoiner` two records (existing and incoming) are taken as parameters.

Comment: The main difference is with the logic you would implement within `ValueJoiner`. When it is a `reduceByKey` it would be executed for all records and therefore your logic would aggregate *ALL* records. When it is the `leftJoin` in use, your logic would use the value directly and not expect it to be given all the records.